# How to force spring org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat to custom DateFormatter

Tags: java, spring

I have a scenario where I have different types of dates coming, in that case the existing spring conversion is failing as vales coming are in different formats.

Is there a way I can make Spring use my custom DateFormatter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make Spring use my custom DateFormatter ?

Yes but as your use case is specific I believe it is better to use a **custom annotation** to make everything *explicit*.

These `interface`s can be used to accomplish this task:

- [`Formatter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html)
- [`AnnotationFormatterFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/AnnotationFormatterFactory.html)

These classes source code can be used as a reference:

- [`Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.java)
- [`DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.java)
- [`NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/number/NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.java)

You could do something like this:

#### The `UnstableDateFormats` annotation

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface UnstableDateFormats {
  String[] formatsToTry();
}
```

#### The `Formatter` implementation

```
public class UnstableDateFormatter implements Formatter<LocalDate> {
  private final List<String> formatsToTry;

  public UnstableDateFormatter(List<String> formatsToTry) {
    this.formatsToTry = formatsToTry;
  }

  @Override
  public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    for (String format : formatsToTry) {
      try {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
      } catch (DateTimeParseException ignore) {
        // or log the exception
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse \"" + text
        + "\" as LocalDate using formats = " + String.join(", ", formatsToTry));
  }

  @Override
  public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
    // Implement this method thoroughly
    // If you're accepting dates in different formats which one should be used to print the value?
    return object.toString();
  }
}
```

#### The `AnnotationFormatterFactory` implementation

```
public class UnstableDateFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<UnstableDateFormats> {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
    return Collections.singleton(LocalDate.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Printer<?> getPrinter(UnstableDateFormats annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new UnstableDateFormatter(Arrays.asList(annotation.formatsToTry()));
  }

  @Override
  public Parser<?> getParser(UnstableDateFormats annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new UnstableDateFormatter(Arrays.asList(annotation.formatsToTry()));
  }
}
```

*Don't forget to register the `AnnotationFormatterFactory` implementation*:

If you are using spring mvc you can do it in the web configuration (see [Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-conversion)):

```
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new UnstableDateFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
  }
}
```

See also:

- [Spring Field Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format)

You may also want to consider:

- [Configuring a Global Date and Time Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format-configuring-formatting-globaldatetimeformat)

Comment: When I did this, I am getting an error saying 

Wrapped by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface com.table.domain.search.TableContext
where the TableContext is an interface and it was working fine previously ?